# How to use subdivision modifier properly on this cylinder?

Tags: subdivision-surface

So my friend is trying to make a plane out of a cylinder and we decided to make it smooth but ends up a mess...
[image]

[image]

anyone knows how to fix this issue? :(

Comment: You can't. If you don't have good quads/edge loops, you will have this kind of result. So you'll have to rework all ngons here

Comment: alright, he's remaking it right now lol.

Comment: See this http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/

Comment: add edgesplit modifier and where you need sharp edges Select the Edge and in the N panel under transform > Edge Data > Crease set from 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

I agree with lemon's previous post. Although using a cylinder for a wing seems to make sense, it's just not a good way of creating mesh. Better to either start with a cube and subdivide it as more detail is needed, or learn how to keep good quads/edge loops and just altogether good practices for mesh creation.